# When is the conditional differential entropy, $h(X+Z_1\mid X+Z_2)$, maximized?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, maximum-entropy

Let $Z_1$ & $Z_2$ be 2 i.i.d. RVs, each distributed according to $N(0,1)$, and let $X$ be an arbitrary RV with unit variance.  What distribution of X will maximize this conditional differential entropy $h(X+Z_1|X+Z_2)$?

N.B. Clearly, $h(X+Z_1|X+Z_2) = h(X+Z_1,X+Z_2) - h(X+Z_2)$.  So Gaussian distribution of X will maximize both terms on the RHS.  But will it also maximize the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question hinges on another related question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166689/79206).  Now that the latter is resolved, this question can also be answered easily as follows.

To simplify the notation, let's define $U\equiv X+Z_1; V\equiv X+Z_2$.

First, note that for a given $E[Var(U\mid V)]$, we have $h(U\mid V)\leq \frac{1}{2}log(2\pi e E[Var(U\mid V)]).$  The equality holds when the condition pdf of $U$ given $V$ is Gaussian and the $Var(U\mid V)$ is constant.

2ndly, with https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166689/79206, we know that $E[Var(U\mid V)]\leq 3/2$ and is maximized when $X\sim N(0,1)$.  So $h(U\mid V)\leq \frac{1}{2}log(3\pi e).$

Quite remarkably, when $X\sim N(0,1)$, $U$ & $V$ are jointly Gaussian, so the condition pdf of $U$ given $V$ is Gaussian and the $Var(U\mid V)$ is constant.  Therefore, $h(U\mid V)$ reaches its maximum value of $\frac{1}{2}log(3\pi e)$.